# Can we see the SE leaderboards for Unikong

Tags: feature-request, unikong

It is kinda sad looking at the leaderboards and seeing it is just you and some preset high scores. I would like to see a real highscore board: with every person per site/the entire network with their score and rank seen  by practically anyone. This would encourage more competition and make the game not against the preset high scores, but against everyone.

So can we have an Stack Exchange wide scoreboard for Unikong? If that board is too big: limit to like top 1000 scores or allow a per site wide scoreboard.

Comment: _I made it past 13,000 if that helps... :D_

Comment: http://imgur.com/0BBA1lT

Comment: Oh yeah? http://i.stack.imgur.com/YlGhc.png :D

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN lol you guys are all casuals: http://i.imgur.com/OXdNWZe.png

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat You abused that "shooting the platform" bug, didn't you? *Didn't you?*

Comment: @randal'thor http://i.imgur.com/BShiDM5.png

Answer (score 10):

We don't have data for that. We don't track scores for this at all except in local storage for individual users. This was largely dictated by how we ended up having to host the game - it runs off of our CDN, loaded in an iframe, which means we a) don't really know who you are... and b) we *could* make the submission/tracking part work, but we couldn't verify identity well which means anyone would really be able to post any score to a global leaderboard via a line of javascript.

So the official line is that this is a solo game and if you want to compete, you should invite some friends over to your browser to play against. ;)